# Скрыть элемент при переходе на другую секцию

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, fullpage

подскажите пожалуйста, как скрыть .fp-tooltip при переходе на другую секцию через n-е время. https://codepen.io/alexmillern/pen/KKPYpMO
пример: [клик](http://www.kushconcentrates.co/smart-one-page-hamburger-menu-with-fullpage-js-13211464972306/)
[image: Здесь fp-tooltip статичен при переходе на любой]

```
.fp-tooltip
```

Comment: т.е. Вы хотите чтобы **header** появился и через 2 секунды к примеру скрылся, а точка осталась, при переходе вниз виден лишь **features** и снова через 2 секунды скрывается и видны лишь точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'YOUR KEY HERE',
  sectionsColor: ['#333', '#333', '#333', '#333'],
  anchors: ['header', 'features', 'works', 'contacts'],
  navigation: true,
  navigationTooltips: ['header', 'features', 'works', 'contacts'],
  showActiveTooltip: true,
});
```

```css
.section {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #fff
}
#fp-nav ul li a span {
    background: #fff;
}
#fp-nav ul li a.active + .fp-tooltip{
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 3s forwards; 
    animation: cssAnimation 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    0%   {opacity: 1;}
    90%  {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/dev/src/fullpage.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/dev/src/fullpage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

`animation: cssAnimation 3s forwards;` - 3s это время через которое анимация отрабатывает